# How to make a contract which will use some other token for minting NFTs

Tags: solidity, nft

a solidity newbie here. I have been playing around with ERC-721 contracts and I have a question regarding the price.

The usual way of assigning price is this:

```
uint256 public price= 0.05 ether;
```

How can this price be set in some other toke? Is it only restricted to ETH?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `0.05 ether;` is only for Ether since it's the native token on ethereum blockchain. But you can easily use an erc20 as payment for a mint.

I did a quick google search and found something that will help you.

You should look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72540628/how-do-i-accept-an-erc20-token-for-nft-mint-payment-instead-of-eth).

Hope this helps